# Is it legal to use counterfeit money as defense against burglars and robbers?

Tags: currency

I have produced small amounts of counterfeit money, I keep this in a few wallets in a few rooms in my house. When going outside I always have one such wallet with me in case I get robbed. Is using counterfeit money for this specific purpose legal?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: This is quite the scheme to be able to give away fake cash if you are robbed.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't say which country you're in, it's likely that you're interested in United States law.

You are *probably* in the clear here, though you're getting close enough to the edge of breaking the law that I wouldn't be confident about not being prosecuted and/or convicted.  The relevant laws in this case appear to be [18 USC 471](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/471), [18 USC 472](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/472), and perhaps [18 USC 514](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/514).  All three of them begin "Whoever, *with the intent to defraud*...".  It's questionable whether creating counterfeit money as a burglar decoy counts as defrauding the burglar.

Comment: Bringing such counterfeit money into a shop may bring you closer to the threshold.